# How to get the product Id from a meta key and a meta value in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I am new to coding. But I did this and got an array of values as expected. Fantastic!

```
$thearray= get_post_meta( $product, $metakey, true );
```

What if i had the meta_value (and of course the key) and wanted the post_ids as an array?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**You can't get a post Id from a defined meta key and meta value**, as many post ids can have the same meta key and meta value.

You could use a custom SQL query only if the meta value for the meta key is unique, like:

```
function get_post_id_from_meta( $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT post_id 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = '%s' 
        AND meta_value = '%s'", 
    $meta_key, $meta_value ) );
}
```

It should work (only if the meta value for the meta key is unique).

EXAMPLE USAGE:

```
$post_id = get_post_id_from_meta( '_color', 'Red' );
```

---

**Get meta data from the `WC_product` Object**

With the `WC_product` Object use the `WC_Data` method `get_meta()` from a defined meta key:

```
 $value = $product->get_meta('some_meta_key');
```

---

**Get meta data from the Post Id *(or product Id)***

With WordPress `get_post_meta()` function from the product id from a defined meta key:

```
$value = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'some_meta_key', true );
```

where in both cases `some_meta_key` need to be replaced by the correct desired meta key.

Comment: Please add global $wpdb in your function get_post_id_from_meta.

function get_post_id_from_meta( $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT post_id 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
        WHERE meta_key = '%s' 
        AND meta_value = '%s'", 
    $meta_key, $meta_value ) );
}